# Emacs + Slime + slime-fuzzy-completions-mode: Emacs opens completions buffer and switches to that buffer... How to prevent this?

Tags: completion, slime

In a Common Lisp REPL buffer using Slime, I am using slime-fuzzy-completions-mode to complete symbols when pressing . Upon doing so, Emacs opens a new buffer (in same frame) and presents possible completions. So far so good.

When pressing `SPC` the currently selected completion is taken and inserted at point BUT Emacs then switches to the previously opened completion buffer ... See attached screenshots.

[image: Before completion selection]

[image: After completion selection]

What I want is Emacs closing the completion buffer after the completion selection. I just want to be taken back into the first buffer and continue typing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on GitHub that worked for me.
https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/580#issuecomment-711070373

> Same here (`v2.26`, Emacs 27.1 on Mac). Apparently,
> `slime-fuzzy-window-configuration-change` is invoked even if the window
> configuration doesn't change while the fuzzy completions are active.
>
> ```
> (defun slime-fuzzy-window-configuration-change ()
>   nil)
> ```

Comment: Thx. Works for me.